# Determine toggle state?

Tags: jquery

How to determine toggle state of element?

Comment: Might need a little more information . . .  Otherwise, you are likely to get answers like 'True'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
.is(":visible")
```

See **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** and **[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)**

Comment: You forgot the quotes around `:visible` ;-)

Comment: Could be... or could be `.is(':checked')`. More info needed!